# How to fix types.ArgumentError: argument 1: <class 'TypeError'>: expected LP_POINT instance instead of pointer to POINT?

Tags: automation, desktop-application, pyglet, pywinauto, pyautogui

I'm using selenium, pyautogui, pywinauto to automate the desktop app. I'm automating settings app. And based on the user's input value I'm trying to change the value of the current brightness of the computer. but it keeps on showing this error.

The most important part is I wasn't getting the error 3 weeks ago and everything was working fine but yesterday when I run the script it started throwing the error.

The complete error I'm getting is-
**ctypes.windll.user32.GetCursorPos(ctypes.byref(cursor))
ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 1: : expected LP_POINT instance instead of pointer to POINT**

Some part of the script where the process get stuck and starts throwing the error. the script  stop running at the 3rd line...

```
slider = content_of_page.find_element_by_id("SystemSettings_Display_Brightness_Slider")
slider.click()
pyautogui.dragRel(args.value, 0, duration=1.0, button='left')
pyautogui.click()
```

I'm using pyautogui=0.9.47

Comment: Well, I could reproduce the issue on my side. Technically it's mutual issue of both libraries. Changing order of imports fixes the problem. But I will try to overcome it completely.

Comment: You can try fix by `pip install https://github.com/vasily-v-ryabov/pywinauto/archive/ctypes_conversion_fix.zip` Will make PR and release 0.6.8 later.

Answer (score 2):

I also had the same issue and reinstall did not help. I found solution in: https://github.com/asweigart/pyautogui/issues/353

After installing pywinauto==0.6.6 all work ok for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact problem just right now.

I fixed it by un- and reinstalling pyautogui and pywinauto.
The problem persisted after reinstalling pyautogui, but was fixed after reinstalling pywinauto. So I am not sure if you need to reinstall both or just pywinauto.

Hope that helps!
Andreas